# AngularJS - Service variables are undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know exactly what the issue here is, but I'm trying to set up a service that does something similar to this (However, on a much more complex scale) the example displays the problem.

Basically, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
$myService.init().then($myService.print);
```

and receive output saying `Hello world`, however instead the output is `undefined`. Example:

```js
angular.module('myService', [])
  .service('$myService', ['$q',
    function($q) {
      this.variable = null;
      this.init = function() {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          this.init = "Hello world";
          resolve(null);
        });
      };

      this.print = function() {
        alert(this.variable);
      };

    }
  ]);

angular.module('app', ['myService']).controller('Controller', function($myService) {
  $myService.init().then($myService.print);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='Controller'>...</div>
```

Comment: hint : Try logging `this` in the different functions, and see what you get.

Comment: and for solving use `bind` or closure: `.then(function(){$myService.print();});`

Comment: @Grundy using `bind` was the solution.

Comment: hm, but where you assign something to `this.variable` instead of `this.variable = null;`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, like you a bit confused with `this` keyword.
In javascript `this` refers to function context and depends from how function was called.

So, here

```
this.init = function() {//here this referes to service object,
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    this.init = "Hello world";//and here this refers to promise, and not to service object.
    resolve(null);
  });
};
```

also and in this case

```
$myService.init().then($myService.print);
```

to `then` passed reference to function, and `this` inside function refers to Promise object.

Another mistake: you assign your `variable` just once in code, so it always *null*.

*Sidenote:* not use *alert* for debugging, because it block main thread, so any promises or async functions would not be resolved until alert shown.

So you can fix all like in snippet below.

```js
angular.module('myService', [])
  .service('$myService', ['$q',
    function($q) {
      var that = this;//save reference to service object for using in $q callback
      this.variable = null;
      this.init = function() {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          that.variable = "Hello world";//assign to variable instead init, also use that instead this
          resolve(null);
        });
      };

      this.print = function() {
        console.log(this.variable);//output to console instead show alert
      };

    }
  ]);

angular.module('app', ['myService']).controller('Controller', function($myService) {
  $myService.init().then($myService.print.bind($myService));//pass to then function with this binded to service object
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='Controller'>www</div>
```

Comment: The way I did it was `var init = function() { }.bind(this);` with all of my methods and I have not had any issues, and could keep my `$myService.init().then($myService.print);` syntax. Any issues with this?

Comment: @Hobbyist, can add to answer your updated code? in most cases you not need in binding to `this` directly, only when you pass it as callback

Answer (score -2):

```js
angular.module('myService', [])
  .service('$myService', ['$q',
    function($q) {
      this.variable = null;
      this.init = function() {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          this.init = "Hello world";
          this.variable = "Hello world";
          resolve(null);
        });
      };

      this.print = function() {
        alert(this.variable);
      };

    }
  ]);

angular.module('app', ['myService']).controller('Controller', function($myService) {
  $myService.init().then($myService.print);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='Controller'>www</div>
```